# Determination of frequency components via FFT in R – problems at phase because of a constant offset

Tags: r, signal-processing, fft

by use of FFT in R I want to determine all frequency components (amplitude, frequency and phase) of any signal. My FFT routine has worked proper on my self-provided testfiles except on my last testfile. Here was an offset on one phase – the other phases were calculated correctly.
By trial and error I detected that there is a constant offset about 1.255.

In R I implemented the FFT as described in the following:

- At steady state I take 5 seconds of the signal
- Of this segment of signal – below only signal – the mean must be subtracted  (if necessary)
- Now the signal will be windowed (Hanning) and some zeros were padded (zero padding)
- Next you apply the FFT to the signal
- A matrix is created with two columns – column one is for the bins and column two for the magnitude of the FFT
- The rear half of the matrix is cut off
- Now maxima and minima of the magnitude were identified and saved with related bin in a new matrix (column one bins, column two magnitude)
- And again the new matrix will be shortend. Any amplitude under 0.45 will be cut off
- Finally the calculation of amplitude, frequency and phase will take place

  - amplitude

    - `magnitude/(length(signal)/4)`

      - `length(signal)` depends on the sampling rate
  - frequency

    - `bin*sampling rate/length(signalw)`

      - `length(signalw)` depends on the sampling rate and the zeros padded
  - phase - case analysis because the magnitude is a complex number `fft(signalw)=x+iy`

    - `x>0,y>0` - - - - `atan(y/x)` - - - - - - - Case 1
    - `x>0,y<0` - - - - `atan(y/x)+2*pi` - - - Case 2
    - `x>0` - - - - - - - `atan(y/x)+pi` - - - - - Case 3
    - `x==0,y>0` - - - `0.5*pi` - - - - - - - - - - Case 4
    - `x==0,y<0` - - - `1.5*pi` - - - - - - - - - - Case 5
- bin-number, amplitude, frequency and phase will be saved in a matrix

  - this is my result matrix

To examine this phenomenon of the constant phaseshift of 1.255 I created a testfile (with a sampling rate of 1000 Hz, whereby… whatever…).

Frequency: - - `seq(from=0.3,to=64.3,by=2)`

Amplitude: - - -`rep(x=c(0.5,1.1,1.134,0.75),length.out=33)`

Phase: - - - - - `seq(from=0,to=8,by=0.25)`

With `signal=ampl[i]*cos(2*pi*freq[i]*t+phi[i])` you get a signal with 33 cosine waves.

The next picture is showing the table of setpoints.

[table of setpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0tc4.png)

When I do the FFT routine as described above I get following results:

[my result matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9VBM.png)

Now let’s have a quick comparison with the table of setpoints:

- The red marked values have a constant offset of 1.255
- The yellow marked values are reduced by 2*pi (periodicity)
- The green marked value isn’t calculated correctly – see question…
- The non-marked values were calculated right
- Which case is used for calculating the phase

  - Case 2 (frequency 38.3 and 40.3) - red marked
  - Case 1 (frequency 42.3 ... 50.3) - red marked
  - Case 1 (frequency 52.3) - yellow marked
  - Case 3 (frequency 54.3 ... 64.3) - yellow marked

Just for some further examination I putted all these frequencies in an underdamped step.
Again a comparison with the table of setpoints:

- all phases have the constant offset of 1.255

Notes:

- The constant offset is occurring in every case of the phase case analysis
- In this forum I found the hint, to use atan2(y,x) instead of atan(x)

  - But this hint doesn’t solve my problem – hopefully I implemented it right…
- Watch the frequency of 42.3 Hz, for example

  - In the first result you need to add the offset of 1.255

    - `3.9926288+1.255=5.2476288`
  - In the second result it is probably necessary to consider the periodicity

    - `0.2223801+2*pi-1.255=5.250565`

Questions regarding the constant offset of 1.255:

- How emerge the constant offset?

  - As you can see above some values are calculated correctly. The formulas I am using are always the same!
- The constant offset of 1.255 I got through trial and error.

  - Is there an efficient way to get the exact value?
- How should I complete my phase calculation to get always the right phase?

Additional question:

- How to deal with the green marked value? The phase of the frequency is hard to calculate…

  - Will it be sufficient to raise the zero padded zeros and the sampling rate?

When you need more information please let me know – I will edit my post…

Furthermore I'm very sorry that I'm not able to include more pictures... I have not enough reputation...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share the code you use to generate the Amplitude/Frequency table?

Comment: @mhovd: Sorry, I don't find it anymore... But watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V_dxWuWw8yM) to get the basics...